# I have NSInvalidArgumentException in iOS UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, row

the error is:

```
2013-04-02 14:46:07.180 ECom[7855:c07] -[UITableViewController setItemRow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x768c770
2013-04-02 14:46:07.180 ECom[7855:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setItemRow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x768c770'
```

In the method int the last line of the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"clPanelSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ECOMClPanelDetailViewController *detail = (ECOMClPanelDetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"clPanelSeguePathRow = %d", path.row);
        [detail setItemRow:path.row];
    }
}
```

And the method in the last line is

```
-(void)setItemRow:(int)aItemRow
{
    clDetailItemRow = aItemRow;
}
```

Can't understand what's wrong. Who can help?

Comment: Make sure that the destination controller of the segue is indeed the `ECOMClPanelDetailViewController`, and check that `setItemRow:` is defined on that controller's class as an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it appears that your detail panel isn't what you think it is.   Based on the error message, the `seque.destinationViewController` is of class `UITableViewController`, not `ECOMClPanelDetailViewController`.   That's what you need to track down first.

Second, because of this, when you send your `setItemView:` message, it can't be interpreted and raises the exception.

Begin by looking at where the `destinationViewController is instantiated (maybe your XIB file) and make sure that you have the right classes set.

Answer (score 1):

the `detail` is not a ECOMClPanelDetailViewController, but pointing to a UITableViewController. You can check the segue's identifier in your storyboard to make sure you didn't make a mistake in the identifier name.